# Identify system table in Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, c++11, oracle11g, odbc

ALL,

Is there a way to identify the system tables in Oracle 11g?

If I call SQLTables() API, I will get a list of all tables available. What I'd like is to identify what table is internal Oracle and which one is user-made.

I'm connecting with the `system` account. (a dba one).

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Query e.g. `DBA_TABLES` (which means that you have access to all tables in that database), using the **OWNER** column name as filter. For example:

```
select owner, table_name
from dba_tables
where owner in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');
```

For more owners, query `DBA_USERS`:

```
select * from dba_users;
```

and include any you want into the first query.

Comment: I'm using `SQLTables()` ODBC API. Should I not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `SQLTables()` is. What I posted is what works in Oracle, using any tool (such as SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or ...).

Comment: also if I'm connecting with `system` account how do I differentiate between table I created and the system tables Oracle made for internal use? I also updated the tags so hopefully someone will reply.